# A rhyme riddle puzzle: It can't be made by a Snake

Tags: riddle, wordplay

What am I referring to?

> It can't be made by a Snake,
>
> whether it is asleep or awake.
>
> It can be made by a Beagle,
>
> or sometimes even by an Eagle.

> Found in various places,
>
> we humans can easily make,
>
> You dont need hands to make it,
>
> Did this puzzle make your head shake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the answer is a

> Footprint

Reasoning

> Snakes don't have feet so cannot make them but beagles and eagles both have feet as do humans and footprints can be found in various places.